# How to prevent conflict between two separate docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, docker-container

I have two separate projects in two separate folders.
when I run one of them, the second one cannot run because of conflict between ports.

The problem is for ElasticSearch image.
Followings are two docker-compose files:

```
# /home/foder_1/
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch_ci:
    image: elasticsearch:7.14.2
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 9200
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    env_file:
      - ./envs/ci.env
    container_name: elasticsearch_ci_pipeline
```

Second one:

```
# /home/folder_2/
version: '3'
services:
  
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.14.2
    expose:
      - 9200
    volumes:
      - elastic_search_data_staging:/var/lib/elastic_search/data/
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
```

When I run `docker ps`, I see the second ElasticSearch container created but it doesn't show its ports.

How can I solve the problem?

**Update**: 
The problem is in this situation, my web application (django-base) cannot connect to the second elastic search instance.

Also, when I change port number in the second docker-compose for ES, (for example adding 9500 as Expose), again the port numbers of ES is the default ports (9200, 9300) plus my new port (9500) and my web application cannot connect to none of them.

Comment: What error message do you get, if any? 'expose' doesn't map the port to a host port, so there shouldn't be any conflicts.

Comment: @HansKilian I updated my post. The problem is when first compose file is up, in second compose file, ES will not run.

Comment: How does your Django app connect to the elasticsearch container? It needs to be on the same bridge network. Also 'expose' doesn't really do anything, since the image already contains an `EXPOSE 9200 9300` statement, so you can safely leave it out.

Comment: To reiterate @HansKilian's point, `expose:` in a `docker-compose.yml` file does almost nothing and it can almost always be deleted.  There's a potential conflict around different Compose setups publishing the same `ports:` but that doesn't match what you're showing.  Since each container internally has its own port space you don't need to change the container ports just to talk between containers, even if you have multiple Elasticsearch containers running; just connect to `elasticsearch:9200` or `elasticsearch_ci:9200` as appropriate.

Comment: (`docker ps` won't show published ports if your Compose setup doesn't include `ports:`, but that's not a problem unless you need to call one of these Elasticsearch instances from outside of Docker.)

Comment: There's one thing is not very clear to me. Your Django application is served on your host and not as a docker container, right? If it is on the host, then as it is said by others, you need to publish the ports on your host (using `ports:`). Otherwise, if Django app is also a container on another network you cannot access the elasticsearch containers. They are completely isolated by their own networks.

Comment: @hup No, both of my projects are in docker-compose. for shorten post, I haven't write continue of docker-compose files in the post.

Comment: How can I force ES to listen on my desired port?

Comment: @DavidMaze As you said, ES just responses to my request if I send to 9200 port. Is there anyway to change listening port of ES?

Comment: So you have a Django app in `/home/foder_1/docker-compose.yml` and `/home/foder_2/docker-compose.yml` and you want that the Django app from `folder_1` to connect to ES on `folder_2`? It wouldn't be possible. As I said, they have their own network. The services of the same projects can communicate among themselves.

Comment: @hup No, I want to connect django_1 to ES_1 and django_2 to ES_2. The problem is when docker-compose of folder_1 is run, docker-compose of folder_2 cannot run. ES_1 and ES_2 have a conflict on 9200,9300 ports.

Comment: I see! Then, it is very strange that there's a conflict without publishing the ES ports. I suggest to take a look at your Django config and published ports of that service in your compose files.

Comment: Just a remark, not related to your question, `elasticsearch:7.14.2` is vulnerable to Log4Shell CVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what the problem is. 
My server has only 4 GBs of RAM and when one `elasticsearch` is running, other instances of elasticsearch cannot start because the first instance consumes the most of RAM.

if you want to run two separate instances of elasticsearch, you shoul consider at least 6 GBs of RAM per instance.